# key-chord gives error when pressing chord

Tags: key-chord-mode

When I start to press keychord binding, after first char it flashes me an error:

`symbols value as variable is void: eldoc-mode`.

Here is my chord definition:

`(key-chord-define-global "ss" 'other-window)`

I installed key-chords via melpa with cask, I'm using emacs-nox 24.5.1. Any help will be appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 2):

Something might have changed recently..

This is the offending code in key-chord-mode:

`(when eldoc-mode
                (eldoc-pre-command-refresh-echo-area))`

You can work around it my requireing eldoc in your init.el

`(require 'eldoc)`

What needs to be fixed in key-chord is to check if the variable `eldoc-mode` is defined before checking it's value.

Comment: someone added that  offending code a short while ago http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?action=browse;diff=1;id=key-chord.el

Comment: I fixed it now so should come to melpa soon.

Comment: The code should just use `(and (boundp 'eldoc-mode) eldoc-mode)`. End of story.

Comment: @Drew what about `(bound-and-true-p 'eldoc-mode)`?

Comment: @PythonNut: Yes, same thing, assuming Emacs 22 or later.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick but its ```(bound-and-true-p eldoc-mode)``` since the bound-and-true-p macro does the quoting for you.  


Also, I did not realise that the URL of the emacswiki change was relateive so what you see there is my fix and not the edit that introduced the error.. And it might change...

Answer (score 1):

Is `ss` bounded to `other-window`?

Then there is a hook inside other-window function, that hooks up with eldoc-mode? If so, you need to initialize eldoc-mode first.